# Rename mounted volume for dmg file (permanently in the dmg)?

Tags: mount, dmg

I have a DMG file for an application. Created with some list of scripts that are not readily accessible for quick re-run. The content is fine but it mounts a volume name that is broken. It is broken because a specific format is expected by other scripts.

Is there some way to edit this existing DMG file to rename the volume it will mount as?

To illustrate:

- DMG file name: my_macos_image.dmg
- I doubleclick on my_macos_image.dmg
- DMG content is mounted at "/Volumes/my_mac_image_oops_this_part_is_too_much"
- I wish to edit DMG file to change "/Volumes/my_mac_image_oops_this_part_is_too_much" to "/Volumes/my_mac_image"

How can I do this? (or can I..)

Comment: The volume name it will be mounted as is the folder name you choose when you use New Image->Image from Folder in Disk Utility so you could try repackaging it that way.